# How to deploy a project to /project instead of project.example.com with Vercel

Tags: seo, vercel

For SEO purposes it useful to be able to have all your content under one domain. I want to be able to take seperate projects and deploy them under a path, but still use all the other paths for my main homepage. I want CI/CD to work so I can still just push my work to github and be done. How would one implement that? An example would be deploying a blog to /blog instead of blog.example.com

Currently I am deploying all my seperate projects to subdomains, but if one project get a lot of links the domain authority of my homepage doesn’t benefit. Is it even beneficial to use different tech stacks under the same url?